# Change a boolean value after a click on a button in Django

Tags: ajax, django, button, boolean

I need some help regarding button clicks and boolean value changes.

My model:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
starter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='topics')
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
isReported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
startPrice = models.IntegerField(validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])
```

I want to change the state of the field "isReported" from the default value "False" to "True" after a click on a button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Report</button>
```

I already googled and found something like this on SO ([How do I change a value in django on button click in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070515/how-do-i-change-a-value-in-django-on-button-click-in-html)) but I am lacking knowledge of the concept presented in this thread. Unfortunately this was the only helpful information I could find.

How can I change the boolean value in my database after a single button click? It is not neccessary to change the value back on this button.

I somehome tried to adapt the code of the link:

views.py:

```
def ajax_change_status(request):
isReported = request.GET.get('isReported', False)
pk = request.GET.get('pk', False)
# first you get your Job model
job = Topic.objects.get(pk=pk)
try:
    job.isReported = isReported
    job.save()
    return JsonResponse({"success": True})
except Exception as e:
    return JsonResponse({"success": False})
return JsonResponse(data)
```

xxx.html:

```
    <form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="change" role="button">Report</button>
    </form>
```

```
<script>
     $("#change").on('click', function () {

  var pk = '{{ topic.pk }}'
  var isReported = 'True'

  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/change_status/',
    data: {
      'isReported': isReported
      'pk': pk
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.success) {
        alert("ajax call success.");
        // here you update the HTML to change the active to innactive
      }else{
        alert("ajax call not success.");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

I am trying to understand the concept, but (obv.) it is not working.

```
POST /request/xxx-xxx-xxx-5622149-3/ HTTP/1.0" 200 5472
```

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50070914/2052575) on the thread you linked solves your problem perfectly.  Can you expand on the concept(s) you don't understand?

Comment: hi v25, I edited the code with my adapted version. Any input appreciated!

Comment: Firstly, in the javascrpit snippet, keep the line           `'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),` as the AJAX request needs to pass this back for [security reasons](https://kylebebak.github.io/post/csrf-protection).  However it's not obvious what's not working, as you haven't really posted any error traceback. The last line you added looks like a sucessful HTTP response (200). Are you seeing an error elsewhere?